# Skipping Fragments During Swipes with a FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-viewpager, swipe, fragmentpageradapter

I'm fairly new to Android programming, so this is [hopefully|probably] a silly question.

I'm copying the behavior of an iOS app that has 4 tabs along the bottom.

Initially, the only 2 that are active are the first and the last. The center 2 only get activated after a successful search.

I like the swipe-to-change behavior of Android (I may add it to the iOS app).

However, I'm not sure of the correct way to skip the two inactive center so a swipe from right to left goes from the first tab to the last (and vice-versa).

I don't see any hooks in the published API. I guess I can mess with the item being returned in getItem() (instead of sending one of the middle ones, I go straight to the last one), but I'm wondering if that's the correct way to do it. I'm concerned, because you instantiate the instance on getItem(), so that means it may not be the best place to do this.

Any feedback on this? I know that with Android, there's often a dozen ways to do something, but usually only one or two "correct" ways.

I'd like to do this the correct way.

Comment: I guess what I need to do is override whatever code is used to select the "position" input. I'm not sure where that's done. I'll look for it.

Comment: I think I know where I need to go here. I need to override the ViewPager with my own class. I'm currently instantiating the default class.

Comment: [This critter](https://guides.codepath.com/android/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter) seems to have what I need. I'll answer the question for posterity when I'm done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I said I'd report how I "solved" the issue. It isn't 100% perfect, but it works, and I think that it's basically doing the right thing.

First of all, I used [the TabLayout system](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html), where you create a TabLayout object, and give it a [ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) and [FragmentPagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html).

I found out that the [Tab class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.Tab.html) is final. You can't subclass it. That meant that I needed to use the Fragments for the state (enabled/disabled). You can turn clickable on and off for the tab, but I added an "enabled" flag to the Fragment subclass. This is what I use to query the state of the tab.

I then created an embedded class in the Adapter subclass. I implemented [ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html) (It's an interface):

```
private class MyTabPagerListener implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener
```

I add that to the TabLayout as the listener:

```
mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new MyTabPagerListener(mTabLayout,this));
```

Then I implemented the "skipping" code in the onPageSelected() method. I try to anticipate where the selection is going, so I can jump to the appropriate tab. The whole idea is to figure out the direction. If the next selected tab is disabled, then we keep going:

```
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    AWrapperBaseFragment    fragment = (AWrapperBaseFragment)mAdapter.getItem(position);
    mSkipToPosition = -1; // This will inform the "wrap up" function that we need to skip to another tab.

    if ( !fragment.isEnabled() ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Page " + position + " is disabled, selecting a different one.");
        int oldPosition = mTabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition();
        if ( position > oldPosition ) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Going up.");
            for ( int i = position + 1; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++ ) {
                AWrapperBaseFragment    comp_fragment = (AWrapperBaseFragment)mAdapter.getItem(i);
                if ( comp_fragment.isEnabled() ) {
                    mSkipToPosition = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if ( mSkipToPosition == -1 ) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Going down.");
            for ( int i = position - 1; i > -1; i-- ) {
                AWrapperBaseFragment    comp_fragment = (AWrapperBaseFragment)mAdapter.getItem(i);
                if ( comp_fragment.isEnabled() ) {
                    mSkipToPosition = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    mSelectedPosition = position;

    if ( mSkipToPosition == -1 ) {
        mSkipToPosition = mSelectedPosition;
    }

    Log.d(TAG, "Page selection will " + ((mSelectedPosition != mSkipToPosition) ? ("change from " + mSelectedPosition + " to " + mSkipToPosition) : "not be changed." ));
}
```

This function sets a semaphore, which is exercised in the state change callback:

```
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    Log.d(TAG, "New Scroll State for page " + mSelectedPosition + ": " + state);
    if ( (state == 0) && (mSkipToPosition > -1) && (mSkipToPosition != mSelectedPosition) ) {
        Log.d(TAG, "This is a disabled page, so page selection will change from " + mSelectedPosition + " to " + mSkipToPosition + "." );
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(mSkipToPosition, true);
    }
}
```

Like I said, it isn't perfect. There's a noticeable hesitation, and you still see the disabled tab contents go by (so don't leave slop in disabled tabs).

It's a whole lot more complicated than an iOS solution, but I think it will work. I haven't finished testing it.